# How to delete a line with starts with function by python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, wikipedia

I want to delete a line in 50,000 wikipages. Because that line is a dead external web page link. For example,  have a look at [this wiki page.](https://ta.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?title=abdominal_muscle&action=edit&section=2)
The line consists of two parts. one is starting text another is the URL.
THe URL varies for each and every word but the text always starts with '*தமிழ் இணையப் பல்கலைக்கழக அகரமுதலியில் '. How can i delete the line which starts with fuction?

```
Sample code :

#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
wikiPage = '''==உசாத்துணை== 
* தமிழ் இணையப் பல்கலைக்கழக அகரமுதலியில்  [http://www.tamilvu.org/slet/servlet/o33.o33searh?CboSelect=1&TxtSearch=abdominal+muscle&OptSearch=&id=All abdominal muscle]'''

# part1 is a line of  'starts with'
part1 = '* தமிழ் இணையப் பல்கலைக்கழக அகரமுதலியில் '
part2 = '[http://www.tamilvu.org/slet/servlet/o33.o33searh?CboSelect=1&TxtSearch=abdominal+muscle&OptSearch=&id=All abdominal muscle]'
print(wikiPage.replace('part1',''))
```

How to delete part2 too? Please note that part2 is a url which differs fro every wiki page.

Comment: Please make an attempt to A) provide all relevant info directly in the question, instead of using offsite links, and, B) solve this yourself.

Comment: How about   if line.startswith(r'blablabla'):

Comment: Kindly excuse me. i added the sample code

Answer (score 0):

Create a new list (or however you store lines) of lines, then iterate through the old list, and only add lines that don't start with that string.

```
START_OF_LINE = "*தமிழ் இணையப் பல்கலைக்கழக அகரமுதலியில்"
new_lines = [] # or however you store lines

for line in lines:
    if line.startswith(START_OF_LINE):
        pass
    else:
        new_lines.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
s_line = '*தமிழ் இணையப் பல்கலைக்கழக அகரமுதலியில்'

lines = [line for line in lines if not line.startswith(s_line)]
```